# Get data if results object is empty in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Bit of an odd question to word correctly, but I have an issue in Crystal Reports for Enterprise by SAP.  I designed a report with 2 user input parameters (year & item1).  Lets say they pick a year that has no item1, meaning the results object is empty.

They people reading the report still want what they selected in the title of the report with an accompanying "No Data Found", but the problem item1 is an ID, and they want the text representation of item1 which is a different column.  When I drag that column onto the report it is of course null because the data comes from the results object which is empty at this time...

Is there any way to have a separate query that could just use the item1 ID to too look up the name, or am I out of luck because the selected parameters have no results?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a subreport that wasn't linked to the main report, thus having 2 separate data objects.